# Create a Custom Button on Report

Tags: reporting, custom-button, reports-api

I have following requirement

1. I want to create a Report with Contacts.
2. Now i want to export these contacts to a Campaign using a Custom Button.

**Here I don't know how to create a Custom button in report.**

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption your report is nothing more than a table of contacts with a certain filter, I suggest you use a list view instead of a report. Contact list views already have a button 'Add to Campaign'.

[image: A list view]

Comment: Thanks for Response
is it not possible to create a custom button in Report?
Because i have some filter condition which is not achieve in listview